# Center a menu with left align items

Tags: css, menu, center

I need to design a menu, in which the menu is always centered, with variable number of items, browser resolutions, and the items would be aligned to the left (menu centered in the page, but items aligned to the left).

[image]

(As you can see it is not centered at all).

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.extPanel{
 background-color:#555;
 padding: 0px 20% 0px 20%;
 display: table;
}

.split{
    clear: both;
}

.menuElement{
 float:left;
 background-color:#aaa;
 margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 text-align: center;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="extPanel">

    <div class="menuElement">item1</div>
    <div class="menuElement">item2</div>
    <div class="menuElement">item3</div>
    <div class="menuElement">item4</div>

    <div class="split"></div>
    External Panel. 20% left and right padding.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the external div has 20% padding in order to center the items. Items float to the left. Items are not centered at all because a remaining space exists in which item4 doesn't have enough space, so it floats to the next line.

And if the menu would have only one menu item, this item float to left so is more obvious that the menu is not centered. If I try to use some style to center all the items (text-align or something like this), item4 would appear centered below item2, and I need that the items are align to left.

I need:

- Menu to be centered in the page, with any number of items
- Items centered
- Cross-browser compatibility (to IE8 at least, and mobile explorers)
- No JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block;`.

You can add the following code:

```
.extPanel {
    text-align: center;
}
.menuElement {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; //ie
    zoom: 1; //ie
    //remove float: left;
}
```

Comment: But item4 is centered also, and i need it align to left:

http://codepen.io/anon/full/ziyJK

Answer (score 0):

instead padding, you could simply use `margin` and `inline-block` for childs.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/quByg

```
 .extPanel {
      margin:0 20%;
text-align:justify;
    }
    .menuElement {
      display:inline-block;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      margin:0 20px 20px 0;
      border:solid;
    }
```

Comment: Problem of your answer is that item4, appears in the middle and i need it align to left. I need that complete menu is center in page, but items align to left.

Comment: it can be : or text-align:center or text-align:left; or text-align:justify ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nuvlw wich one would you like best ?

Comment: what you want is not possible via only CSS unless container and itemm have a fixed width , then you could use something like .menuElement:nth-child(4) {float:left;} .. in the case you know container can only hold 3 item per line., then , in this figure, once you get on 6th/7th item, problem will show up again :(

Comment: sorry, my previous coment was wrong. If you only have one menu item, this is no centered in page (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LirHd). I need that if has one menu item the result was like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBEio if has two like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/deEbG if have three like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lobxp if have four like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qynHB . I need that the whole menu centered in page, but, if items don't have enougth space and need float to next line, elementos align to the left... I think is complicated (may impossible...)

Comment: funny, looks like our last comments got mixed up on time line :)

Comment: I found the solution by combining all your answers:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/odhrp
You can see that works for 1 element to 9 or more... Thx very much for help!

Comment: Perfect, glad i could give you some hints

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `text-align: center;` on the surrounding body. Then `.extPanel` needs a `margin: 0 auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/markdelorey/ttZgZ/

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, menu is not centered at all. The background color allows see this problem, it has more grey margin in the right than the left.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by combining all your answers.

You can found it here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/odhrp

I used diffent IE hack here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/flEsm

As you can see, works with one element, two, three... When items menu don't fit in extPanel max width, items goes to next line, align to left, and menu is still centered.

```
.extPanel {  
   background-color:#555;
  text-align:center;
  display: table;   
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: justify;
}
.menuElement {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px 20px 0;
  border:solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And text-justify: distribute solve the problem with text-align: justify in IE.